# Any way to view stdout of a program after it has been started in gnome-shell?

Tags: linux, gnome-shell, stdout

So, if I run a program through the menus in gnome-shell, is there a way to view `stdout` and `stderr`? Or is there some kind of hack to achieve this functionality?

Or is everything just sent to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, `gdm`/session start-up scripts redirect `stderr` & `stdout` to either:

```
~/.xsession-errors
```

or

```
~/.cache/gdm/session.log
```

With `systemd` and recent `gdm` versions, everything is redirected to `systemd journal`, so one way to get that output is:

```
journalctl -b _PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
```

Comment: I think gnome-session doesn't necessarily run anymore (I'm on gnome 3.14, because pgrep doesn't find it, though I'm definitely in gnome ;)

Comment: @ufotds - it all depends on your particular setup, but on a normal gnome setup it definitely runs (I'm on a vanilla gnome 3.14.2 install and `pgrep gnome-session` works fine).

Answer (score 3):

The command suggested by don_crissti didn't show anything for me, but I just do:

```
journalctl -f
```

in a terminal tab that I always leave open (and opens automatically on boot) so I have realtime feedback of all logging from systemd on my computer.

If desired, you can use the match filters from journalctl to limit the noise, but for now I like to have everything at hand.